# Make the integrate.quad function return only the analytical value

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration, calculus

The integrate.quad function in scipy displays the analytical and absolute error of the integration. How do
I make it output just the analytical portion?

The code below returns (21.333333333333332, 2.3684757858670003e-13). I just want 21.3333

```py
from scipy import integrate
x2 = lambda x: x**2
integrate.quad(x2, 0, 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can print only the `21.3333`

```
from scipy import integrate
x2 = lambda x: x**2
results = integrate.quad(x2, 0, 4)

print(results[0])
```

The output will be:

```
21.333333333333336
```

Answer (score 0):

`integrate.quad(x2,0,4)` returns a tuple. Indexing is one way of dealing with this:

```
my_result = integrate.quad(x2, 0, 4)[1]
```

Another option is unpacking the tuple, using underscore for the values you are not interested in:

```
_, my_result = integrate.quad(x2, 0, 4)
```

Note that the underscore is still accessible like any other variable would have been (you could also have called it `a`, or `temp`, or `not_interesting`), but using an underscore is a Pythonic way that will make other people reading your code understand that the variable will not be used.